# Excel supported japanese character but csv not supported in extjs

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, extjs

Excel supported japanese character but csv not supported in extjs.

In grid i having japanese character. While downloading i could see properly data in excel sheet. But not able to see in CSV. Can you please help me on this?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3p81

Comment: Can you please give me a example that how UTF BOM need to be use in extjs code

Comment: I wonder how you open the CSV file and what tool did you use. I tried opening the resulting CSV file in MS Excel, VS Code and Notepad. They look exactly the same as in the grid. Sometimes I encounter this issue if the tool opens the file with a different encoding. Most of the time you can just change the correct encoding in the tool you open the CSV file with.